# In what languages can you redefine methods/functions in terms of themselves?

Tags: literate-programming

I'm interested in trying literate programming. However, I often that the requirements are stated in a general but then exceptions are given much later.

For example in one section it will say something like Students are not allowed in the hallways while classes are in session.

But then later there will be section where it says something like Teachers may give a student a hall pass at which point the student may be in the hall while class is in session.

So I'd like to be able to define `allowedInTheHall` following the first section so that it doesn't allow students in the hall, but then after the second section redefines `allowedInTheHall` so that it first checks for the presence of a hall pass, and if it's missing then delegates back to the previous definition.

So the only way I can imagine this working would be a language where:

1. you can redefine a method/function/subroutine in terms of it's previous definition
2. where only the latest version of a function gets called even if the caller was defined before the latest redefinition of the callee (I believe this is called "[late binding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Late_binding)").

So which languages fulfill support these criteria?

---

PS- my motivation is that I am working with existing requirements (in my case game rules) and I want to embed my code into the existing rules so that the code follows the structure of the rules that people are already familiar with. I assume that this situation would also arise trying to implement a legal contract.

Comment: You need a third criterion: The latest version of the function will call only the previous version and not itself or older versions. Although this *might* fit in under the first.

Comment: You *could* do this with late binding (any language that explicitly "looks up" a name supports it, e.g. PicoLisp)... most of it only requires that you have mutable globals though: e.g. Scheme with `set!` can redefine functions in terms of the previous definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well to answer the direct question,

> you can redefine a method/function/subroutine in terms of it's previous definition

...in basically any language, as long as it supports two features:

1. mutable variables that can hold function values
2. some kind of closure forming operator, which effectively amounts to the ability to create new function values

So you can't do it in C, because even though it allows variables to store function pointers, there's no operation in C that can compute a new function value; and you can't do it in Haskell because Haskell doesn't let you mutate a variable once it's been defined. But you can do it in e.g. JavaScript:

```
var f1 = function(x) {
    console.log("first version got " + x);
};

function around(f, before, after) {
    return function() {
        before(); f.apply(null, arguments); after();
    };
}

f1 = around(f1,
            function(){console.log("added before");},
            function(){console.log("added after");});
f1(12);
```

or Scheme:

```
(define (f1 x) (display "first version got ") (display x) (newline))
(define (around f before after)
   (lambda x  
      (before) (apply f x) (after) ))
(set! f1 (around
  f1
  (lambda () (display "added before") (newline))
  (lambda () (display "added after") (newline))))
(f1 12)
```

...or a whole host of other languages, because those are really rather common features. The operation (which I think is generally called "advice") is basically analogous to the ubiquitous `x = x + 1`, except the value is a function and the "addition" is the wrapping of extra operations around it to create a new functional value.

The reason this works is that by passing the old function in as a parameter (to `around`, or just a `let` or whatever) the new function is closing over it referred to through a locally scoped name; if the new function referred to the global name, the old value would be lost and the new function would just recurse.

Technically you could say this is *a form* of late binding - the function is being retrieved from a variable rather than being linked in directly - but generally the term is used to refer to much more dynamic behaviour, such as as JS field access where the field might not even actually exist. In the above case the compiler can at least be sure the *variable* `f1` will exist, even if it turns out to hold `null` or something, so lookup is fast.

Other functions that call `f1` would work the way you expect assuming that they reference it by that name. If you did `var f3 = f1;` before the `around` call, functions defined as calling `f3` wouldn't be affected; similarly objects that got a hold of `f1` by having it passed in as a parameter or something. Basic lexical scoping rule applies. If you want such functions to be affected too, you *could* pull it off using something like PicoLisp... but you're also doing something you probably shouldn't (and that's not any kind of binding any more: that's direct mutation of a function object).

---

All that aside, I'm not sure this is in the spirit of literate programming at all - or for that matter, a program that describes rules. Are rules supposed to *change* depending on how far you are through the book or in what order you read the chapters? Literate programs aren't - just as a paragraph of text usually means one thing (you may not understand it, but its meaning is fixed) no matter whether you read it first or last, so should a declaration in a true literate program, right? One doesn't normally read a reference - such as a book of rules - from cover to cover like a novel.

Whereas designed like this, the meaning of the program is *highly* dependent on being read with the statements in one specific order. It's very much a machine-friendly series-of-instructions... not so much a reference book.

Comment: Well you would only execute any logic after the very last (re)definition. This makes it easier to audit that the logic of the program follow the rules. If there are changes to the rules it makes it easier to update the code. Mainly I'm trying to avoid collating the requirements from the rules since that process is error prone and harder to audit.

Comment: My understanding of literate program is as said in Wikipedia "A literate program is an explanation of the program logic in a natural language, such as English, interspersed with snippets of macros and traditional source code." Well the explanation of the program logic already exists (ie the rules and regulations written by committees and lawyers and such), so I just want to embed the code within it.